# HyperLedger Composer 0.19 How to encrypt/decrypt data using private/public key?

Tags: encryption, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, private-key, public-key

I have a usecase where I have to encrypt data using a participant's public key before adding the data to the chain.

I have already implemented issuing identity and creating cards through following the example here.
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#card-api-errors--resolutions

The problem is the example only returns certificate and private key.

However, I need public key to encrypt data before adding to the chain so I can decrypt it with the private key later (when retrieving).

Can anyone please help me out? Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: So you need to encrypt the data before sending it in a transaction, which means it needs to be done client/ server side. Smart contracts written using `composer` cannot `require` nodejs modules so using encryption libs like `crypto` are not possible. You can do it if you use the native SDKs though.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal Thank you for the response.
I know I have to do this on the server-side (which I am doing). I need to figure out how to get the PUBLIC KEY of the identity card. The example above only provides private key and a certificate.

Comment: the certificate is the public key afaik. Fabric does not use the same cryptographic tools that Ethereum and bitcoin do